# svm one classification accuracy without labeled data

Tags: python, dataframe, svm

I am trying to detect anomaly data from dataset with OneClassSVM.
I have not input labels and Input dataset haven't any label.

how I calculate accuracy and recall , ... .
Because  when we have output label's  we can calculate from this method:

```
#Check the prediction performance
print(classification_report(y_test, costomized_prediction))
```

And we can compare real label by prediction label.
But now when we don't have real label how we can calculate accuracy, recall, ...?

Comment: You can not calculate them if you don't have the corresponding labels.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy. recall etc are dependent on the ground truth (or labels). So you need to hunt for them to understand how your model is performing.